# How to make Xephyr to hide its background (rootless mode like in Cygwin/X)

Tags: linux, xephyr

Cygwin/X and Xming can run in "rootless" mode that seamlessly integrates "inner" windows to the host environment.

Is there similar mode for Xephyr or some equivalent program? I want Xephyred windows to be like usual windows, but without ability to lock screen or generate keystrokes or mess with other windows.