# Start multiple Firefox (Portable) instances doesn't work using -no-remote switch

Tags: windows-10, firefox, portable, windows-10-v1709

Having a running Firefox installed, I want to start Firefox Portable downloaded from [heise](https://www.heise.de/download/product/firefox-portable-22559/download). On Windows I'm running `FirefoxPortable.exe -no-remote` which was posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/126189/start-multiple-instances-of-firefox), but always get the error: *Another instance of Firefox is already running. Please close all other instances of Firefox before you try to start Firefox Portable Edition*.

Things I tried:

```
set MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1
FirefoxPortable.exe -CreateProfile test -no-remote
FirefoxPortable.exe -ProfileManager -no-remote
```

It's not a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/553066/firefox-is-already-running-with-no-remote) since the author seems to start two instances of the same firefox installation (which also has the same default profile). In my case, I have a installed firefox instance (default profile folder `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles`). The portable firefox seems to use the path `Data\profile` relative to `FirefoxPortable.exe`.

How can I start multiple Firefox instances? Is the `-no-remote` switch from the [Firefox docs](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) not working any more?

I'm using the latest portable version 65 of Firefox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Firefox is already running" with -no-remote](https://superuser.com/questions/553066/firefox-is-already-running-with-no-remote)

Comment: I don't see as a duplicate since he's starting another instance of the _same firefox_ with the same user profile. Since I have a locally installed instance running and want to start _firefox portable_, the portable one is using a different profile located in `Data/profile` instead of `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles` from installed firefox.

Answer (score 7):

## Method 1 - Flags

After testing this myself, the solution provided in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/553066/firefox-is-already-running-with-no-remote) does indeed also work for two different installations of Firefox:
Edit: According to OP, this doesn't work on their setup. The second method does, however.

```
firefox -no-remote -profile "profile_path"
```

So if you already have a running instance of your regular FF running and want to also open portable, you'd do

```
FirefoxPortable.exe -no-remote -profile "Data\profile"
```

Conversely, to open the regular install with portable already running, you'd do

```
firefox.exe -no-remote -profile "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"
```

<sub>(Actually, I only tested using absolute profiles and I already shut down my Windows PC. You might have to replace `%APPDATA%` with the actual path.)</sub>

---

## Method 2 - .ini

Another way to start multiple instances of FF portable is to add

```
AllowMultipleInstances=true
```

to the `FirefoxPortable.ini` in the same folder as the .exe (create it if it doesn't exist already) which, going by the documentation, automatically calls it using the `-no-remote` flag for you (Using this method does not guarantee the use of separate profiles though).

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work, I get the same error about an already running instance. `-profile` seems to be ignored. Even when the folder doesn't exist like `FirefoxPortable.exe -no-remote -profile asdf` I get the same error, no message about the non-existing profile.

Comment: Even `AllowMultipleInstances=true` in `Other\Source\FirefoxPortable.ini` doesn't change this. No difference if using the `FirefoxPortable.exe` without arguments or with `-no-remote -profile "Data\profile"`. Also tried `Data/profile` as path and powershell as well as cmd.

Comment: Ok my fault, I missed the readme which inform that `Other\Source\FirefoxPortable.ini` is only a example. We need to copy (or create) this file to the root directory where `FirefoxPortable.exe` is located. Now the `AllowMultipleInstances=true` parameter works, which seems also more comfortable since you can start firefox using the exe file without open a command-promt first.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me.
https://portableapps.com/comment/228523#comment-228523

1. From the directory where your `FirefoxPortable.exe` is (let's call it `appRootDir`) you go to directoty `Other\Source\`
2. Copy the file `FirefoxPortable.ini` to the `appRootDir`
3. Change line `AllowMultipleInstances=false` to `AllowMultipleInstances=true` in the copied `FirefoxPortable.ini` in `appRootDir`

Other options like profile directory (`--profile`) are set in `FirefoxPortable.ini`.

```ini
[FirefoxPortable]
FirefoxDirectory=App\Firefox
ProfileDirectory=Data\profile
SettingsDirectory=Data\settings
PluginsDirectory=Data\plugins
FirefoxExecutable=firefox.exe
AdditionalParameters=
LocalHomepage=
DisableSplashScreen=false
AllowMultipleInstances=true
DisableIntelligentStart=false
SkipCompregFix=false
RunLocally=false
```

I use `FirefoxPortable` of version `124.0.1`